# Hive how to get current timestamp in format 2020-04-17T19:17:56.017719Z format

Tags: hive, timestamp, format, hiveql, utc

I am using Hive and have an important task at hand, which needs the current timestamp in the format `2020-04-17T19:17:56.017719Z`.

Any help around exact solution for this in Hive, would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
with time as (
select reflect('java.util.Date','getTime') as millis
)
select concat( from_unixtime(floor(millis / 1000   ),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"), '.',cast((millis % 1000)as int),'Z')
from time
```

Result:

```
2020-04-26T11:12:35.590Z
```

Or one more method

```
select concat(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split(current_timestamp,'\\.')[0]),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"),'.',split(current_timestamp,'\\.')[1],'Z')
```

Result:

```
2020-04-26T11:28:13.433Z
```

One more method using regexp_replace:

```
select regexp_replace(current_timestamp,'(.*) (.*)','$1T$2Z')
```

Result:

```
2020-04-26T11:50:51.804Z
```

If you need to get microseconds in Hive, the dirty trick is

```
with time as (
select reflect('java.util.Date','getTime') as millis, reflect('java.lang.System','nanoTime') as nano 

)
select concat( from_unixtime(floor(millis / 1000   ),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"), '.',cast(millis%1000 as int),cast(nano%1000 as int),'Z')
from time
```

Result:

```
2020-04-26T21:53:31.261356Z
```

But this is not real microsecond-precision.

Comment: Thank you leftjoin. Can I also get the milliseconds uptil 6 places as I mentioned in my original question. 2020-04-17T19:17:56.017719Z. The solution you shared does this till 3 places which I appreciate you sharing. Would appreciate a way to take it till 6 places.

Comment: @akki You cannot currently get real microsecond precision timestamp in Hive. You need Java 9 Instant.getNano. And hive built on Java 8. See updated answer

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. In my current sql, this timestamp column is fetched as a part of the select statement from my table. Actually it is hard to include this in the comma separated columns in my select statement as this is selecting from time table. Do you know of a way to achieve this? Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Note that 'Z' in this format stands for UTC timezone. I'm not sure simply appending it to a timestamp in arbitrary local timezone is the right thing to do.

Comment: @akki Suppose you are in UTC. if not, and you need to convert timestamp to UTC from some other timezone, look on the to_utc_timestamp function. time table (CTE) is only my example. You may not need it at all. select directly.